# Find Closest Value to Input in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The first rows of my dataframe are shown below. The columns are longitude, latitude, and value. This dataframe extends for 30 million rows.

```
-179.979166666666657 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.9375 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.895833333333343 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.854166666666657 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.8125 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.770833333333343 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.729166666666657 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.6875 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
-179.645833333333343 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
```

I am trying to find the closest longitude and latitude point to a given input, and then print out the value associated with the closest longitude and latitude. I have tried to convert the dataframe into an array, and then search for the minimum value using this algorithm:

```
def match (lon, lat):
    min=10000
    minindex=-1
    for x in range (len (mintemparr)):
        if (abs ((float (lon))-float (mintemparr [x][0])))+(abs ((float (lat))-float (mintemparr [x] 
        [1])))<min:
             
              min=(abs ((float (lon))-float (mintemparr [x][0])))+(abs ((float (lat))-float 
             (mintemparr [x][1])))
       minindex=x
    result=mintemparr [minindex][2]
    return result
```

However, this is very slow. Is there a more direct way to search for the closest value within pandas rather than converting it into an array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your dataframe index on longitude or latitude? if not, consider indexing on them. Then you should be able to search for the longitude and latitude. won't that work?

Answer (score 3):

```
def find_closest(df, lat, lon):
    dist = (df['lat'] - lat).abs() + (df['lon'] - lon).abs()
    return df.loc[dist.idxmin()]

>>> find_closest(df, -179, 90)
lat     -1.796458e+02
lon      8.997917e+01
value   -3.400000e+38
Name: 8, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using pandas. I will make a column for the differences with the given values and then the square root of the sum of squared differences of latitude and longitude. Then I'm getting the min.
Assuming that your data frame is called **df** with columns **latitude, longitude** **and value**:

```
lon=-179.979164

lat=89.979162

df['sumofdiff']=df.assign(landif=df['longitude']-lon).assign(latdiff=df['latitude']-lat).eval("x=(landif*landif)+(latdiff*latdiff)")['x'].apply(np.sqrt)

df[df.sumofdiff == df.sumofdiff.min()]


    longitude   latitude         value      diff  sumofdiff
0 -179.979167  89.979167 -3.400000e+38  0.000005   0.000005
```